# Usage of brackets in sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Compute the following, where complements are taken within S:

1.{A×B}∩{S×B}
2.(A×B)∩(S×B)

I don't understand the difference between "{" and "(" used in set notation.

Comment: $\{A\times B\}$ isn't a Cartesian product, it is a set with one element and that element is a Cartesian product. $(A\times B)$ is simply $A \times B$, the parenthesis is added to resolve ambiguity in the expression.